# Вывод информации из MySQL в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, syntax, sqlexception

Есть код на SQL:

```
SELECT  users.login AS 'Все заказы' , items.title AS ' '  FROM `orders`
JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id 
JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id
```

Сам код в IntelliJ IDEA

```
public  void vivod(String table) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT  users.login AS `Все заказы` , items.title'  FROM `orders`" +
                 "JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id" +
                 "JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id";

        Statement statement = getDbConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery( sql );
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println( res.getString( "orders" ) );


        }

    }
```

В SQL выводится корректно, а при вставке в IntelliJ IDEA выдает ошибку

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL
> syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
> for the right syntax to use near 'items ON orders.item_id  = items.id'
> at line 1

Конечный результат должен быть такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего происходит ошибка?

Comment: Для начала - замените имя поля выходного набора, состоящее из пробелов, на что-то вменяемое. И замените прямые кавычки вокруг имён полей выходного набора на бэктики - прямые кавычки используются для обрамления литералов.

Comment: @Akina ,менял , та же ошибка осталась

Comment: *менял* добавьте в вопрос ТОЧНО, на что именно менял. И, поскольку, ошибка явно не от MySQL, а от Java - то ещё и Java-код.

Comment: @Akina, добавил код Java
Странно что в sql ошибки не выводит, а тут ошибка

Comment: У Вас отсутствуют пробелы между токенами. Неужели было трудно посмотреть, что именно получается в переменной `sql`?

Comment: @Akina, я конечно извиняюсь за тупой вопрос,но намекните где.
я пока что новичок в данной сфере.

Comment: Вы что, не знаете, как в Java вывести значение переменной "на посмотреть"? в отладчике, в какой-нить alert, в файл наконец... только не спрашивайте меня, как это сделать - я с Java вообще не работаю. А когда выведете - вот тогда и сравните текст SQL и то, что наваялось в переменной.

Comment: @Akina нельзя быть таким злым

Comment: @Anastasiya Одни роют носом, пока окончательно не уткнутся в тупик. Другие на первой же кочке начинают "я новичок" - и сидят сложа ручки, ждут ответов... Можно. А в половине случаев пока не прилетит - не встряхнутся, так и будут сидеть. Нужно.

Comment: @Akina,поверьте мне,форум это последняя вещь куда я обращусь за информацией.Я много перерыл всего,но опять таки повторюсь как человек который только учиться, все усвоить за один присест я не могу и вот приходиться думать и спрашивать для меня о трудной задаче у вас, а для вас она может как семечки,решается на раз два

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всем спасибо,все решилось

```
public void zakazy(String table) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT  users.login  , items.title  FROM `orders`"+
        "LEFT JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id JOIN `items` ON items.id   = 
         orders.item_id";

        Statement statement = getDbConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery( sql );

        System.out.println("Все заказы");
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(  res.getString("login")  +  " - "  +  res.getString("title") );
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что это просто опечатка, сморите:

```
public  void vivod(String table) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String sql = "SELECT  users.login AS `Все заказы` , items.title'  FROM `orders`" + //<------------ здесь
                 "JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id" +
                 "JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id";

        Statement statement = getDbConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet res = statement.executeQuery( sql );
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println( res.getString( "orders" ) );


        }

    }
```

После `items.title` у вас одинарная одинокая ковычка. Попробуйте просто ее удалить. Но вообще, идея должна подсказывать где что не так. Вот еще что...  По поводу обнесения в косые кавычки названий таблиц - это не обязательно, если название таблицы не совпадает с зарезервированным словом в бд (например user, но у вас users поэтому все ок). На вот этой строчке так же должна выпасть ошибка:

```
res.getString( "orders" )
```

Дело в том, что итоговая таблица будет иметь две колонки - users.login и items.title (что вы, в общем-то, и выбрали (кст тут тоже не имеет смысла указывать `AS 'Все заказы'`  поскольку доступ то вы получаете из resultSet)) - необходимо будет поотдельности выбирать:

```
System.out.println("User login: " + res.getString( "login" ) );
System.out.println("Title: " + res.getString( "title" ) );
```

Если вы захотите объединить результаты двух в таблиц в одну - см документацию по group_concat

Comment: насчет одинарной ковычки,да я опечатался(
советы которые вы дали к сожалению не помогли

Answer (score 0):

Я обычно вывожу в консоль текст запроса
System.out.println("sql=" + sql);

Чаще сразу видно, где опечатался. Если не видно, то копируйте из консоли и несите это в клиент SQL. Оно Вам подскажет. И скорее всего сразу найдете ошибку.

Comment: Все равно так же(

Answer (score 0):

При конкатенации строк в Java переменную типа String у вас SQL будет в одной строке, причем без разделителей новой строки.

Поэтому SQL будет примерно такой

```
SELECT  users.login AS `Все заказы` , items.title AS ' ' FROM `orders`JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_idJOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id
```

Сразу видно, что неверное поле  `orders.user_idJOIN`

Для того чтобы этого не происходило, в Java переменной, нужно добавлять пробелы в начале, либо в конце строки, если происходит слияние кода.

```
String sql = "SELECT  users.login AS `Все заказы` , items.title AS ' ' FROM `orders`" +
             "JOIN `users` ON users.id = orders.user_id" +
             " JOIN `items` ON orders.item_id  = items.id";
```