# Как реализовать запрос с массивом параметров в ManyToMany Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

У меня есть продукт который может иметь несколько категорий, продукт и категории связаны `ManyToMany`.

Подскажите , как реализовать запрос с выбором продуктов, которые имеют хоть одну категорию из массива ?

**Пробовал:**

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Product p join p.categories c where c.name = ANY(:categories)", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Product> findProductsByCategories(@Param("categories") String[] categories, Pageable pageable);
```

Но такой вариант не работает.

**Ошибка:**

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'x'ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B4702000...' at line 1`

**Entities:**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private LocalDateTime data;
    private int mainValume;
    private int mainCost;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "product_has_category",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")})
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();

}


public class Category implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", targetEntity = Product.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Comment: Почему не работает?

Comment: @RomanC Ошибка - `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'x'ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B4702000...' at line 1`

Comment: Это значит, что неверный синтакс у SQL, например вот [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1260979/204920) нельзя делать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC не поддерживает установку списка в качестве параметра. Каждое значение в списке должно быть отдельным параметром.

Это несомненное неудобство и в hibernate есть для этого поддержка, хибернейт сам генерирует запрос разворачивая переданный список и создавая необходимое количество параметров. В вашем коде проблема, потому что нельзя использовать native запрос, т.к. при этом никакая генерация не происходит. БД ругается, так как в вашем случае вместо параметра подставляется, скорее всего, сериализированное значение массива, и понятное дело, что синтаксически запрос совсем неверный (включите лог SQL hibernate-a - уровень `DEBUG` для  логгера `org.hibernate.SQL` и увидите, какой запрос при этом сгенерирован).

Запрос на JQL/HQL типа такого должен работать:

```
FROM Product where categories.name IN (:categories)
```